# Extract only the constant value in a linear equation

Tags: javascript, python, c#, regex

I am trying to extract just only the constant value i.e. "c-value" with sign from a linear equation of type `ax+by+c`.
Note :- Linear equation is input as string.
for ex:- `2x+3y+4` Output = +4
**or** `2x+3y-4`  Output = -4
**or** `-3+2y+1x` Output = -3
**or** `2+6x+1y`Output = 2
**or** `4y+3-5x`Output = +3
In each of the above example i want only the c-value with sign i.e the constant value.

I tried many regex pattern code. But not able to get any general solution to extract the constant value
Below is the best i can get in python 3 but it's also not working for me in many cases.

```
conatsant_c = re.complie(r'([+-]?[0-9]\d*)([^x|^y])')
```

Comment: First, I would recommend you replace `[0-9]\d*` with a more concise `[0-9]+` or `\d+`, to check for one or more numbers. Second, you probably want to have the second character class just be `[^xy]`, as that will check for all characters that are not `x` and `y`.

Comment: You can use the regex `-?\d+(?![a-z])`, `(?![a-z])` being a *negative lookahead*.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JFfsHw/1/)

Comment: @CarySwoveland that fails for e.g. "11x+3y+3", it just selects all but one digit at the start. How about `.match(/[\-+]?\d+(?=[\-+]|$)/)[0]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes but only for this examlpes. not working for 2x+3y-4+y5

Comment: Thanks using ```-?\d+(?![a-z])``` worked for me...

Comment: @Andran i have checked this regex ```-?\d+(?![a-z])``` is working on your case also

Comment: @Sameer not working for t6-6+7t

Comment: That is the same as `0x+13t-6`; it would never be seen as `t6-6+76`. Moreover, the equations of lines never have a variable's coefficient follow the variable (`t6`), even though it is equivalent. If you want to permit expressions such as `t6-6+76` you need to re-write your question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yours answer not vorking for 11x+22y+4

Comment: @CarySwoveland as soon as the coefficients are single digit your solution is working but in case of double digit or float value it is not working..Is there a way we can generalise the regex expression ?

Comment: The regex I suggested is not limited to single-digits (`\d+` matches one or more digits). I would assume that if coefficients could be floats at least one of your several examples would contain a float. `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![a-z])` allows for integers or floats (but not `1.25e3`). Please edit your question to clarify, and add an example with a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex, which uses a negative lookahead to assert there is no letter after the number:

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![\d.]*[a-z])
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hy6EJU/1)

This will work with floating point numbers as well.

In python:

```
import re

strs = ['21x+3y+45',
        '2x+3y-4.2',
        '-3.4+12y+1x',
        '2+6x+41.2y',
        '4y+13.1-5x'
        ]

for s in strs:
    const = re.search(r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![\d.]*[a-z])', s)
    print(const.group(0))
```

Output:

```
45
-4.2
-3.4
2
13.1
```

Comment: `-?[\+|\-]{0,1}\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![\d.]*[a-z])` so will be the most accurate

Comment: @Andran capturing a `+` is redundant, numbers are always positive unless there is a `-` sign in front of them. Also what you propose allows for `--` which would not be a valid number. And `[\+|\-]` allows there to be a `|` in the string, which is definitely not valid.

Comment: you can test my answers

Comment: Good catch with `(?![\d.]*`.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the general solution..It worked..What if i want to extract the coefficient of x. my solution was this ```([-]?\d*)?(x)``` but it is not working for float or double int.

Comment: @Sameer `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=x)` should work: https://regex101.com/r/hy6EJU/3

Answer (score 0):

```js
let secondText = "1.23x+4.56y-7.89";
let cKoef = secondText.match(/[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?!\w)/)[0];

console.log(cKoef)
```

```js
let mathText = "2222x+3333y+4444";
let cKoef = mathText.match(/([\+|\-]{0,1}[\d*])+(?![\w])/)[0]

console.log(cKoef);
```

Comment: Note `[\+|\-]` is the same as `[+|-]`, though I expect you want  `[+-]` (to avoid matching `'|'`). Also, `{0,1}` is usually written `?`,  `[\d*]` is the same as `\d*` and `[\w]` is the same as `\w`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?!\w)` well? ))

Comment: As I said, I don't think you want to match `|`. If you fix that and add `-?` you will have what I suggested in a comment above, but I was wrong. @Nick fixed it in his answer.